# DrawerLayout is being overlapped by other items

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to build an menu.

To build this menu I'm using a DrawerLayout.

But I'm having some issues showing the DrawerLayout because my Listview is overlapping everything.

What do I need to change on my XML code to prevent this?

My menu:

[image]

ListView overlapping the menu

[image]

My code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <!-- Menu -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#029688"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <!-- Listview is here -->

    <ListView
        android1:id="@+id/lvevents"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android1:layout_below="@+id/bar"
        android:dividerHeight="6dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android1:id="@+id/imgvloading"
        android1:layout_width="64dp"
        android1:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `DrawerLayout` is the root layout of the activity. The first child view of the `DrawerLayout` is your content, and the second is your actual drawer. Try rearranging to following and adjusting as necessary:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android_layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_below="@id/bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvevents"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
            android:dividerHeight="6dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgvloading"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#029688"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Additionally, you should remove the unnecessary declaration of `xmlns:android1` and replace any instances where you've used it with `android` (this has been done in the example I've provided)

Answer (score 1):

Your `DrawerLayout` should be the root layout, for example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Place your main content here -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_parent"/>

    <!-- And the layout for your nav menu here -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_menu_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="#ff1cac"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'ListView' must be placed inside your 'content_frame' and 'DrawerLayout' should be used as a root view:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ListView
            android1:id="@+id/lvevents"
            android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android1:layout_below="@+id/bar"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:dividerHeight="6dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#029688"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```